# Shake and Growl on French Horn

Tags: notation, practice, learning, french-horn

I came across some interesting notation in a piece I'm playing earlier this week, and I'm really not quite sure what the composer intended for me to do.

I play French Horn, and here's the notation (2 before I):

[image: Shake and Growl]

(Sorry for the poor quality of the image). The best I can think of for this is a vibrato and a flutter, but that's just a guess. The "growl" note also has a Z over it, which is new to me as well.

Can anyone translate this for French Horn usage?

Comment: Bring a wolf to the first rehearsal, just in case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are jazz articulations, and as a french horn player you'll really just have to do your best imitation of what a trumpet player would do. You might want to ask a trumpet player in your ensemble for some advice and demonstration.

What I'd suggest for the shake is a VERY rapid lip slur from the written note to about a fifth above. It's written forte, and is not supposed to be pretty, but you do need to keep it under control. Practicing on mouthpiece only might be a good starting point if you're having trouble. For the growl, your best bet would probably be a flutter-tongue.

Comment: Interesting - I wasn't expecting it to be jazz articulations, but that does make sense.  I'll ask around in trumpet-land for some demonstrations.  Thanks for the advice!